# How do I generate beeps in kivy?

Tags: python, android, kivy

I'd like to be able to synthesize music on an android phone in a kivy app

Simple beeping would be a good start.

So, for instance, how would I do something like:

```
play(440Hz, 1 second)
play(550Hz, 1/2 second)
play(660Hz, 1/2 second)
play(880Hz, 2 second)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the kivy audio documentation [here](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.core.audio.html), we can use the SoundLoader class to play any audio. Download audio of your choice and play it in this manner.

```
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader

sound = SoundLoader.load('mytest.wav')
if sound:
    print("Sound found at %s" % sound.source)
    print("Sound is %.3f seconds" % sound.length)
    sound.play()
```